# What is the difference between @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY) and @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.FALSE)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

According to [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/LazyToOneOption.html),
Using FALSE will eagerly load the association and using NO_PROXY will give back the real object loaded when a reference is requested. But doesn't eager-loading mean giving the real object back instead of proxy? So, what's the difference between these two?

Please, don't say that @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY) is used to handle lazy-loading for OneToOne. I have seen many answers discussing that issue. My question is, what's the difference between these two options?

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-lazytoone) gives this description:

`@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.FALSE)`: Eagerly load the association (i.e. the associated entity is loaded even if the field is never accessed)

`@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)`: This option will fetch the association lazily while returning real entity object (i.e. the associated object is loaded when first accessing the field)

`@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)`: This option will fetch the association lazily while returning a proxy instead (i.e. the associaed object is loaded when an attribute of that proxy is accessed).

Let's show the difference with two simple entity classes: `Order` and `Address`:

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    // ... some fields here
    private String city;
}

@Entity
public class Order {
    // ... some fields here

    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.FALSE)
    private Address deliveryAddress;

    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    private Address customerAddress;

    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)
    private Address alternateAddress;

}
```

When you load an `Order`, the `deliveryAddress` is loaded. Always - it doesn't matter whether your code accesses that field, the associated object is loaded anyway. This is eager loading.

The `customerAddress` is loaded lazily: it is loaded not when the `Order` is loaded, it is loaded when your code accesses that field (for example, when you call the getter for that field). If your code never accesses that field the associated object is never loaded. This is lazy loading (i.e. the address is only loaded when used) without a proxy object (i.e. when you access the field you get the real object).

The `alternateAddress` is initialized with a proxy object: when your code reads that field, it will see a proxy object. Only when you try to access data of that proxy object will the real `Address` be loaded from the database.

---

> If real object is returned, how is it lazy-loading? Eagerly loading means returning the real object. Isn't it?

No.

- "Eager loading" means loading associated entity (an `Address`) when the primary entity (the `Order`) is loaded.

  Your code contains a statement like `Order o = entityManager.find(Order.class, 1L);` and Hibernate loads the `Order` **and** the associated `deliveryAddress`.
- "Lazy loading" means that the associated entity (an `Address`) is loaded later (when you try to access that entity or a field of that entity) or maybe not at all (if you never access that data).

  Upon some conditions your code calls `Address ca = o.getCustomerAddress();` and the `customerAddress` is loaded by Hibernate exactly when this call occurs.

  Upon some other conditions, your code calls `Address aa = o.getAlternateAddress();` and gets a proxy object (an object that looks like an `Address` but doesn't have its fields initialized). Later your code calls `System.out.println(aa.getCity());` and only now is the entity for the `alternateAdress` loaded from the database. (Note that even if the proxy object doesn't have its fields initialized it still must contain the information that Hibernate needs to fetch the entity from the database.)

Comment: If real object is returned, how is it lazy-loading? Eagerly loading means returning the real object. Isn't it?

Comment: @KawsarAhmed I've updated my answer. Your assumption is wrong: eager loading / lazy loading has nothing to do with whether you get the real object or a proxy object. Eager loading / lazy loading does only indicate at which moment in time the object will be loaded.